# Subtraction + modified result if negative

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

How do I set up a formula which will subtract one cell from another ***(ex: B2-B3)*** and return the usual result, **UNLESS** the result is negative ***(basically < zero)***, in which case I need it to return  **"$0.00"** instead of "Error" or "Div by 0".

Currently I am using ***=IF(B2-B3<0,"0.00")*** which works fine if the values are negative, but it returns **"False"** if the values are positive.

How do I modify this Excel formula so it will work properly and show the actual result or $0.00 if the result is negative or < 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, you shouldn’t be using quotes. 
`"0.00"` is a text value (sometimes called a string)
that consists of four characters: `0` `.` `0` `0`.

Beyond that, you were very, very close. 
You want `B2-B3` if it’s positive and 0 if it’s negative? 
Just do

```
=IF(B2-B3<0, 0, B2-B3)
```

or,
equivalently,

```
=IF(B2<B3, 0, B2-B3)
```

A slightly different approach is

```
=MAX(B2-B3, 0)
```

which gives you `B2-B3` or `0`, whichever is larger.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - that did it! I had actually tried the first one but it did not work as I did not put spaces after the comma.... Syntax is vital in Excel! I wasn't familiar with the MAX formula so I learned some new stuff - Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm;  that’s odd.   Spaces between the arguments to functions don’t matter;  I just include them for readability.

Comment: Yes that is odd. I obviously did something else wrong. Good to know that spaces don't matter after the comma though....